# Ionic Cordova SQLite works well on browser but does not work persistent in Android device

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing ionic cordova hybrid application. When I test it using browser, application works very well. But I test it in my real device it not works very persistent. It means that SQLite sometimes works well and sometimes do not works well. The following is my code:

app.js

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

    db = window.openDatabase("chatChannel.db", "1", "Demo SQLite Test", "2000");
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chat_channel(id interger primary key, chat_room text, last_text text, username text, chat_channel text unique)");
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chat_content(id integer primary key, content text, channel text, chat_flag integer, username text, date timestamp)");
  });
```

controller.js

```
   var query = "SELECT * FROM chat_content WHERE channel=? ORDER BY date";
    var promise =  $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [subscribeChannel]).then(function(result){
    for(i=0; i<result.rows.length; i++){
        $scope.messages.push(result.rows.item(i));
        console.log(result.rows.item(i));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:
 1. Load your *ng-cordova-min.js* or *ng-cordova.js* and *cordova.js* files last by placing them at the bottom of your  in your *index.html* file
 2. In your app.js file, database initialisation should be the first line i.e.

```
    var db = null;
```

should be the first line at the top. And still in your app.js file,

```
    db = window.openDatabase("chatChannel.db", "1", "Demo SQLite Test", "2000");
```

should be the first line in the platform ready function.
Your code should like something like this in the *app.js* file;

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        db = window.openDatabase("chatChannel.db", "1", "Demo SQLite Test", "2000");

        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chat_channel(id interger primary key, chat_room text, last_text text, username text, chat_channel text unique)");
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chat_content(id integer primary key, content text, channel text, chat_flag integer, username text, date timestamp)");

        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: not clear why movie the files to the end of index will fix the issue? anyway I have the same problem, the execution sometimes work and sometimes not without any error or exception. it's a strange case.